# What is filename+util.m/.h file in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have found a project which have some file for example classname+util.h and classname+util.m. What are those file and how to add them in the xcode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their name is `Categories` and are used to add function and properties to a class.

Suppose that you want extend the `UIViewController` class with a new method.
You create a class:

```
UIViewController+Utility.h/.m
```

with a new method.

When you will import this class in your other class, all the object that inherit from `UIViewController`, will have this method and so for example also `UITableViewController` will benefits of that method.

You can also insert property, but is more complex because you have import:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

and to use te functions:

```
objc_setAssociatedObject

objc_getAssociatedObject
```

Comment: ok got this they create the category of another class thanx. Its a silly question

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about these files actually. This naming convention is used for categories, i.e. code that extends existing classes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: but there is no util category and if i add a category the file name is categoryname+class name.h/.m

Comment: in the example filename+util, "filename" would be some **existing class*, and "util" is meaningless, it's just a word the engineer uses to suggest what these categories are.  For example, NSString+checking, NSString+testing, UIView+moving, UIView+measures and so on.

Comment: Yeah got it now. its a silly question. Missing the file name part.

Answer (score 1):

As the previous answers stated, `ClassName+CustomName.h/m` is a category. A category it's a special `objective-c` class that allows you to add extra functionality to an existing class.

In order to use the methods inside it, you just have to import it in the class you want to use it.

Also be careful a category it's not a class that inherits another class, it's different, a category allows you to add extra features to that class (methods) and that's it. You can't define new properties or class members as you would be able to do into a class that inherits another class.